# Struggling to get HREF values from a list

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm using the following code to get links from a web page

```
        HtmlNode SERP = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"rso\"]");
        if (SERP != null)
        {
            IList links = SERP.Descendants("a").Select(a => a.GetAttributes("href")).ToList();
            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                var result = link;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
```

This prints

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute]

I've tried to combat this through using

```
var result = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Which then produces the error

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' .... are you missing a directive or reference?

Feels like I'm missing something basic but no light bulb is coming.

Comment: Change `Select` to `SelectMany`.

Comment: Using `SelectMany`, it now prints `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute` rather than the URL in the HREF.

Comment: Perfect. Now you are getting somewhere. Now change `IList` to `var`. And read the docs of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1 .

Comment: Done, still printing `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute`

Comment: Read the link to understand _why_ it is doing that. And check the properties of `result` to see what else you might like to use instead.

Comment: Working! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To help anybody in the future, thanks to @mjwills this code works

```
    HtmlNode SERP = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"rso\"]");
    if (SERP != null)
    {
        var links = SERP.Descendants("a").SelectMany(a => a.GetAttributes("href")).ToList();

        foreach (HtmlAttribute link in links)
        {
            var result = link.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```